# Removing headers: \pagestyle{plain} seems not to work

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I am writing my thesis using the package `classicthesis` and I added the headings in order to have the chapter name on the left pages and the section name, without numbering, on the right pages.

I have two problems:

The first one is that I would like to remove the headings from the first page of each chapter, I tried with `\thispagestyle{plain}` but it has no effect. `\thispagestyle{empty}` works but I need to have the page number (in foot).

The second one is that I use a `phantomchapter` for the conclusions and here the headings turn out wrong, indeed they are those of the previous chapter.

The code I use to add headings is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\itshape}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please make this into a full minimal example, not just a sniplet (this greatly increases your chances to get help). What does your sniplet have yo do with classicthesis?

Answer (score 3):

The optional argument of `\ohead` defines the contents of the outer header with pagestyle `plain.scrheadings`. (Page style `plain` is an alias for `plain.scrheadings`). So removing this optional argument will solve your first problem.

For the second one use either `\addchap` or `\addchap*` (no header and no TOC entries) for unnumbered chapters. Then you get the right headers and additionally there is no need to use `\phantomsection`.

Note that it does not make sense to use `\headmark` for the inner and the outer header - then you would have to equal header entries, one on the inner and one on the outer side of the page. So use either `\ihead{\headmark}` or `\ohead{\headmark}` to have the chapter marks on left pages and the section marks on right pages.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\itshape}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\AfterPackage*{classicthesis}
  {\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\nameref{chap:conclusions} and \nameref{chap:another}
\par
\Blindtext[10]
\addchap{Conclusions}\label{chap:conclusions}
\Blindtext
\addchap*{Another unnumbered chapter}\label{chap:another}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

You did not mention where the page number should be on normal pages. I have added them in the outer footer like on the chapter pages.

If you want the default layout of `classicthesis` then remove the `\ohead{\headmark}` and `\ofoot{\pagemark}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\itshape}
%\ohead{\headmark}
%\ofoot{\pagemark}
\AfterPackage*{classicthesis}
  {\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\nameref{chap:conclusions} and \nameref{chap:another}
\par
\Blindtext[10]
\addchap{Conclusions}\label{chap:conclusions}
\Blindtext
\addchap*{Another unnumbered chapter}\label{chap:another}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: Note that `classicthesis` breaks some KOMA-Script features.